# nth-of-type in BeautifulSoup NotImplementedError

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner to Python and I'm trying to implement a webscraper to scrape some survey data. I'm trying to use the nth-of-type CSS selector (because thats the only pseudo-class that BeautifulSoup lets me use) to select all elements that are the 7th  element of the parent (i.e. if you visit the survey, it's all of the Average Scores). I have written this code below that throws a NotImplementedError, even though I have tested the selector in http://jsfiddle.net/3Ycu9/ and I am using only nth-of-type and an attribute selector. Could someone help me figure out why I am getting this error?

```
import requests, bs4
res = requests.get('http://www.eecs.umich.edu/eecs/undergraduate/survey/all_survey.2016.htm')
res.raise_for_status()
survey = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
classes = survey.select('td[colspan=3]')

# select the 7th <td> element in every <tr> tag 
difficulty = survey.select('td[style*="border-top:none;border-left:none"]:nth-of-type(7)')

for i in range(len(difficulty)):
    print(str(difficulty[i].getText()))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `nth-of-type` pseudo-class is partially supported as well. It does not like the additional attribute condition you've applied. This one would go through, for example:

```
td:nth-of-type(7)
```

Having a direct `tr->td` relationship check here would make more sense:

```
tr > td:nth-of-type(7)
```

The markup of this page though is terrible for HTML parsing.

---

A slightly better approach here would be to locate the starting row - the one having the `td` element with `Average Score` header value. Then, we can go through `tr` siblings collecting average scores until the end of the "table":

```
start_row = survey.find(lambda tag: tag and tag.name == "td" and "Average" in tag.get_text(strip=True)).find_parent("tr")

for row in start_row.find_next_siblings("tr"):
    cells = row.find_all("td")

    average_score = cells[6].get_text()
    print(average_score)

    if not average_score:
        break
```

Prints:

```
1.67
1.81
2.51
2.39
2.13
1.67
2.22
2.25
3.08
2.00
1.83
```